# Converting an Integer to Binary in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, parameters, arguments

I have a very specific question about how to convert denary integers into binary through python, but instead only utilising the mod (%) and divide (/) functions.

So far, I have successfully created the actual function and loop itself, but the function seems to loop forever and adds a ranom number of 0s and 1s, despite successfuly converting.

For example, entering 4, outputs [0, 0, 1, 0, 1]. As you can see, it has successfully aquired [0, 0, 1] which is 4 in binary, but adds a 0 and a 1 to the end.

I think it is something to do with the way in which I reference and pass in arguments, but would gladly take some help.

```
num = int(input("Enter the Number"))
def func(num)
    if num == 1:
        alist.append(1)
        return num

    while num != 1:
        modnum = int(num%2)
        num = int(num/2)

        if modnum == 0:
            alist.append(0)
            print(alist)


        elif modnum == 1:
            alist.append(1)
            print(alist)
        func(num)



alist = []
func(num)
print(alist)
print (alist[::-1])
```

Comment: Recursion *and* a loop? Seems like you need to pick one way or the other.

Comment: Could you explain? I know I'm using recursion with a loop, but in the circumstances, should it matter? I'm fairly new, so any help would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: Also why not just use `list("{0:b}".format(num))` to get the list?

Comment: @SudheeshSinganamalla How would I utilise that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Removed recursion.
- Condition should be `num != 0`.
- Use [`divmod` built-in function](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#divmod) for getting both quotient and remainder.
- Removed redundant `modnum` checks.

Assuming these issues we can write

```
def func(num):
    if num == 0:
        return [num]

    binary_digits = []    
    while num != 0:
        num, modnum = divmod(num, 2)
        binary_digits.append(modnum)
    return list(reversed(binary_digits))


num = int(input("Enter the Number"))
binary_digits = func(num)
print(binary_digits)
```

Example:

```
>>> func(100)
[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
num = int(input("Enter the Number"))
def func(num):
    while num != 0:
        modnum = int(num%2)
        num = int(num/2)
        alist.append(modnum)


alist = []
func(num)
print(alist)
print (alist[::-1])
```

You don't need the `if` for appending the right digit, just use the variable   `modnum`. You also have to go through this `while`-loop one more time. The function call at the end `func(num)` gives you these random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a while loop for what you are trying to do. You can try something like this:

```
num = int(input("Enter the Number"))
def func(num):
    #this while loop breaks when num == 1
    while num != 1:
        modnum = int(num%2)
        num = int(num/2)

        if modnum == 0:
            alist.append(0)
            print(alist)


        elif modnum == 1:
            alist.append(1)
            print(alist)
    #when is breaks, append 1 to your list
    alist.append(1)

alist = []
func(num)
print(alist)
print (alist[::-1])
```

This will go into an infinite loop when you enter, **0** as your input. But that is for you to fix

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def func(num):

if num <= 1:
    alist.append(num)
    return 
while num != 1:
    modnum = int(num%2)
    num = int(num/2)

    if modnum == 0:
        alist.append(0)
        print(alist)


    elif modnum == 1:
        alist.append(1)
    func(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can quickly implement this by doing

```
def func(num):
    binary_digits = list("{0:b}".format(num))
    return binary_digits
```